# Где ошибка помогите

Tags: javascript, json

```js
var a, b, c, d, x, y, z;
console.log("Введіть a:");
a = Number(prompt());
console.log("Введіть b:");
b = Number(prompt());
console.log("Введіть c:");
c = Number(prompt());
console.log("Введіть d:");
d = Number(prompt());
console.log("Введіть x:");
x = Number(prompt());

if (Math.abs(x) < d) {
  z = Math.sqrt(a * x + 1) + d
} else {
  if (Math.abs(x) == d) {
    z = Math.sin(b * x + 1)
  }
} else {
  if (Math.abs(x) > d) {
    z = Math.pow(b, 3) * Math.cos(c * x + 1)
  }
}

y = Math.cos(z) + Math.log(z * a / x)
console.log('y=', y, 'z=', z)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 0):

если немного аккуратненько поставить отступы, то

```
if (Math.abs(x) < d) 
{
    z = Math.sqrt(a * x + 1) + d
} 
else 
{
    if (Math.abs(x) == d) 
    {
        z = Math.sin(b * x + 1)
    }
} 
else // <- см. сюда
{
    if (Math.abs(x) > d) 
    {
        z = Math.pow(b, 3) * Math.cos(c * x + 1)
    }
}
```

чувствуете подвох?

Comment: Zhihar. Та я по разному ставил.но не работало вот я и решил спросить

Comment: а что значит "не работало"? какая именно задача была и весь код - может дело в другом? в приведённом коде проблема в скобке - `else` одинокий получается

Comment: я только начал писать код решил проверить и выбыло ошибку, я и твой код подставил не работает. то и есть пока весь код. сори за тупи вопросы

Comment: Аааа всьо понял.Спасибо